# Do action after subview removeFromSuperview (Ios Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, ipad, swift2

Subview Was open using this bit of code from controller A.

```
let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("test") as! DatepickerpopupViewController
    self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
    popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
    popOverVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

And Subview was closed using this Code from Controller B

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3)
        self.view.alpha = 0.0;
        }, completion:{(finished : Bool)  in
            if (finished)
            {

                self.view.removeFromSuperview()


            }
    });
```

Now what i want to do something in the parent view (controller A) after Subview was closed.

Answer (score 1):

Two view controllers messing with the same view is bad design. Change your design so that only one view controller owns the view. Then reacting to the change comes natural. Controller `B` would then tell controller `A` *"remove the subview"* and controller `A` would then do the animation and whatever you want it to do afterwards.

How to do this exactly depends very much on your controllers and app's design, so telling you exactly how to do this is not possible here.